# BCP Importing Nulls instead of empty strings. When I export a null it looks the same as exporting an empty string, what gives?

Tags: null, bcp

Running a simple BCP export on a table with ~ 250 columns.  There are no nulls in it and I run the BCP export.  If I import elsewhere I get nulls out the wazoo but I guess that's normal for BCP.  All the solutions I read are to create your export with NULL populated instead of ,, or empty string.  Issue is when I BCP out a table with nulls I get the same result ,,.  I need the table to import with empty strings.

Comment: Where does it look the same? In an editor? Have you set the editor to show also non-printable characters?

Comment: From what I can tell there are no hidden characters only those which resemble a space.  Whether I export with NULL selected or empty cells there's no difference.  The only workaround I've found is to just import with NULLs and update the columns but this is crazy inefficient and I really would have a much easier time if the BCP could recognize anything to mean blank on import.

Comment: Dru, what do you mean by "when I export with NULL selected"? This is not something you can do with BCP. How are you exporting "with null selected"? Can you share both of your BCP statements, the OUT and the IN?